# How to get LatLngBounds from visible map in jetpack compose

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I try to use the composable `GoogleMap` in my project but now I need the `LatLngBounds` of the visible google map in `onMapLoaded` so I'm able to load some POI for within this boundaries, but I can't find an answer on how I could get this information.

May anybody have a clue for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using [Google Maps Compose Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/maps-compose), the `CameraPositionState` contains a `Projection` which contains a `VisibleRegion`
which contains a `LatLngBounds`.

If you pass in an `onMapLoaded` function to the `GoogleMap` composable (along with a `cameraPositionState`), you can check this value.

You can also set up a `LaunchedEffect` that triggers whenever the camera moves to report the bounds whenever it changes.

I used the following dependencies at the time I'm writing this

- Jetpack Compose: 1.2.0-beta02
- Kotlin: 1.6.21
- Maps Compose: 2.2.1
- Play Services Maps:18.0.2

See the [Maps Compose Repo Install Instructions](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose#installation) for up-to-date requirements.

```kotlin
// Copyright 2022 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Maps1Theme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    // a simple UI that shows the LatLngBounds at the top
                    // and a map below it
                    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
                    Column {
                        Text(
                            text = text,
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
                        )
                        Map(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .weight(1f)
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                        ) {
                            text = it.toString()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Map(
    modifier: Modifier,
    onBoundsChange: (LatLngBounds?) -> Unit,
) {
    val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
        position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(
            LatLng(37.42423291057923, -122.08811454627153),
            16f
        )
    }

    // whenever cameraPositionState.isMoving changes, launch a coroutine
    //    to fire onBoundsChange. We'll report the visibleRegion
    //    LatLngBounds
    LaunchedEffect(cameraPositionState.isMoving) {
        if (!cameraPositionState.isMoving) {
            onBoundsChange(
                cameraPositionState.projection?.visibleRegion?.latLngBounds
            )
        }
    }

    GoogleMap(
        modifier = modifier,
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,

        // pass in an onMapLoaded to report the initial visible region
        onMapLoaded = {
            onBoundsChange(
                cameraPositionState.projection?.visibleRegion?.latLngBounds
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your response.
I don't know why but the camerPositionState doesn't have a attribute called 'projection'. I only hav 'isMoving' and 'position'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ThomasCirksena It requires slightly newer dependencies; I've added the min dependency info that you'll need (in addition to any other dependencies you're using)

Comment: we still can use `val cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 200)
cameraPositionState.move(cu)`